# Getting infinite loop errors and uncertain as to why

Tags: c++

I have to submit an assignment tonight, and the online grading component keeps throwing me errors related to infinite recursion despite my code working fine on my PC.

Essentially, the program takes a file formatted like

> 1 1 2 2

And formats it differently, outputs it with .log, and computes the distance equation. So the result is

> (1, 1) : (2, 2) -> 1.414

If the file is named input1.txt, it becomes input1.log, and so forth. My code passes all tests on Visual Studio, but the grading software we use is older, so it's possible that I might be doing something that could throw an error. This is my code:

```
int main() {
ifstream inFS;
ofstream ofFS;
int x1, y1, x2, y2;
string fileName;
string fileCheck;
string fileName2;
do {
    while (!inFS.is_open()) {
        cout << "Input the file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        inFS.open(fileName);
        if (!inFS.fail()) {
            cout << "Reading file ... ";
            cout << "Done" << endl;
        }
    }
    int length = fileName.length();
    length = length - 4;
    fileCheck = fileName.substr(fileName.size() - 4, 4);
    if (fileCheck == (".txt")) {
        fileName2 = fileName.substr(0, length) + ".log";
        ofFS.open(fileName2);
    }
    if (inFS.is_open() && ofFS.is_open()) {
        while (!inFS.fail()) {
            inFS >> x1;
            inFS >> y1;
            inFS >> x2;
            inFS >> y2;
            double distance = sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2) + pow((y2 - y1), 2));
            ofFS << "(" << x1 << ", " << y1 << ")" << " : " <<
                "(" << x2 << ", " << y2 << ")" << " -> " << fixed <<
                setprecision(3) << distance << endl;
        }
        inFS.close();
        ofFS.close();
    }
    
} while (!inFS.fail());
return 0; }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can go more in-depth if needed.

Comment: Debuggers eat infinite loops for breakfast. Run the program in the debugger that came with your development environment. Wait for infinite loop. Pause program and see where you are. Step through the loop a few times to get a feel for why it's happening. Solve problem or simplify code to focus on the error and ask for help.

Comment: Suggestion: replace `while (!inFS.fail()) { inFS >> x1; inFS >> y1; inFS >> x2; inFS >> y2;` with `while (inFS>> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2)`. The current code tests for validity BEFORE reading the data. You need to test AFTER.

Comment: I have discovered the issue. I will post the solution when my code is more coherent.

Comment: Did not see the replies -- thank you guys for the help - my do-while loop curly brace was causing the errors. I have implemented the while suggestion, thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main issue was a improperly implemented do-while loop, although the while loop fix posted was also an issue. Thank you to everyone who helped. Here is my fixed code.

```
int main() {
ifstream inFS;
ofstream ofFS;
int x1, y1, x2, y2;
string fileName;
string fileCheck;
string fileName2;
do {
    while (!inFS.is_open()) {
        cout << "Input the file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        inFS.open(fileName);
        if (!inFS.fail()) {
            cout << "Reading file ... ";
            cout << "Done" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (!inFS.is_open());
int length = fileName.length();
length = length - 4;
fileCheck = fileName.substr(fileName.size() - 4, 4);
if (fileCheck == (".txt")) {
    fileName2 = fileName.substr(0, length) + ".log";
    ofFS.open(fileName2);
}
else if (fileCheck != (".txt")) {
    fileName2 = fileName + ".log";
    ofFS.open(fileName2);
}
if (inFS.is_open() && ofFS.is_open()) {
    while (inFS >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2) {
        double distance = sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2) + pow((y2 - y1), 2));
        ofFS << "(" << x1 << ", " << y1 << ")" << " : " <<
            "(" << x2 << ", " << y2 << ")" << " -> " << fixed <<
            setprecision(3) << distance << endl;
    }
    inFS.close();
    ofFS.close();
}
return 0;
```

}